# How to Justify Text in c# windows forms application

Tags: c#, winforms

When I write text in a rich text box, I can align the text left or right or center.
But I want to align the text to both sides together, left and right.
How can I do that?

Comment: Why not, almost all the books are designed like this, the text is justified

Comment: I wrote a bunch of code only to discover that RTB doesn't support it.  The best way to see this yourself in by running WordPad, it uses RTB as well.  It has the justify button but it actually has no effect.